# Sorting based on key given in bash

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

So I am trying to sort a text file, call it `tmp`, that contains 4 lines.

The first lines being:

```
table-name grade1 grade2 grade3
Richard 100 99 99
Fred 20 100 60
Alex 57 67 75
```

and have it sorted off based on the grades, if given, or default being their names. If they prompt for `-n` and `-r` it should also reverse and label numerically.

With `$sort` being the field they want to sort.

What I've tried so far is variations of `sort -k"$sort" -nr "$file"` but it only ever sorts off `grade3` even if I ask it to sort `grade1`.

Answer (score 2):

With `$sort` being the column number to have `$file` sorted on, do this:

```
sort -nr -t' ' -k${sort},${sort} "${file}"
```

And here is a proof of concept for the 3 rows you posted:

```
$ cat testfile 
Richard 100 99 99
Fred 20 100 60
Alex 57 67 75
$ 

$ sort -nr -t' ' -k3,3 testfile 
Fred 20 100 60
Richard 100 99 99
Alex 57 67 75
$ 

$ sort -nr -t' ' -k4,4 testfile 
Richard 100 99 99
Alex 57 67 75
Fred 20 100 60
$
```

I hope it helps.